# tcolorboxes in raster not correctly positioned in columns

Tags: tcolorbox, tcbraster

I want to create a 2-column raster of `tcolorbox`es but, only the boxes in the first row are aligned properly. I would expect the result to be 3 rows in 2 columns.

The reason I use `bxTypeA` and `txTypeB` instead of `tcolorbox` is that `bxTypeA` will be slightly more complicated and I do not want to duplicate the code again and again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster}

\newtcolorbox{bxTypeA}[2][]{
    title=#1
}

\newtcolorbox{bxTypeB}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2,raster equal height=rows]

\begin{bxTypeB}{First}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item  aafdsaf
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeB}
\begin{bxTypeB}{Second}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item  aafdsaf
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeB}

\begin{bxTypeA}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item aaa
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeA}

\begin{bxTypeA}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeA}
\begin{bxTypeB}{Third}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item  aafdsaf
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeB}

\begin{bxTypeA}
   These are the menu items:
   \begin{itemize}
   \item
   \item
   \end{itemize}
\end{bxTypeA}

\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of tcbraster]

Comment: remove the empty lines, they force paragraph breaks.

Comment: After I removed the empty lines, it works! Thanks Ulrike!

Answer (score 4):

(This answer is extended from [@UlrikeFischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600149/raster-columns-of-tcolorbox-not-working-in-my-example-please-help#comment1505237_600149).)

Empty lines *inside* `tcbraster` environment will force paragraphs breaks, so the empty lines between `bxTypeA` environments used inside `tcbraster` should be avoided.

```tex
\begin{tcbraster}[...]
  % empty lines at the beginning or end is acceptable

  \begin{bxTypeB}{...}
    contents
  \end{bxTypeB}
  % no empty line(s) here
  \begin{bxTypeB}{...}
    contents
  \end{bxTypeB}

\end{tcbraster}
```